# Checking if a string contains a number, and if so, getting the list from that position

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, regex, string

Suppose I have a string "Monday-Saturday 11: 12 VIKAS KOHLI",
then I want two resultant like "Monday-Saturday" and "11:12 VIKAS KOHLI"

Similarly I have the same string "Monday-Saturday 11: 12 VIKAS KOHLI",
then I want three resultant like "Monday-Saturday" , "11:12" and "VIKAS KOHLI"

I hope I was able to understand my problem.

Thanks in adavance

Comment: Please post what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Your string".split(" ")
```

For the first result just concantinate second and last args.
Will solve your problem

Comment: It will split "VIKAS KOHLI" too

Comment: Then concantinate them... or use regular expressions,but I think they will be hard for you to understand them.

Comment: I'm not the questioner :)

Comment: Sry:) Missed that)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var string = "Monday-Saturday 11:12 VIKAS KOHLI";

console.log(string.split(" ")[0])
console.log(string.split(" ")[1])
console.log(string.split(" ")[2]+ " " + string.split(" ")[3])
console.log(string.split(" ")[1] + " "+ string.split(" ")[2]+ " " + string.split(" ")[3])
```

1. Use split(" ").
2. Combine the text which are separated. Using index as reference

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

```js
var regex = /(\S*) ([0-9]{2}:[ ][0-9]{2}) (\D*)/;

var grouped = "Monday-Saturday 11: 12 VIKAS KOHLI".match(regex);

console.log(grouped);
```